# Im not able to fetch data of variables using for loop in Shell script ksh

Tags: ksh

Now I have the code to work on this file type:
cat myfile.txt

```
XSAP_SM1_100 COR-REV-SAPQ-P09 - 10/14/2013 -
SCHEDULE XSAP_SM1_100#COR-REV-SAPQ-P09 TIMEZONE Europe/Paris
ON RUNCYCLE RULE1 "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE"
EXCEPT RUNCYCLE CALENDAR2 FR1DOFF -1 DAYS
EXCEPT RUNCYCLE SIMPLE3 11/11/2011
AT 0530
:
XSAP_SM1_100#CORREVSAPQP09-01
AT 0640 TIMEZONE Europe/Paris
XSAP_SM1_100#CORREVSAPQP09-02
AT 0645 TIMEZONE Europe/Paris
```

Code is

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=":"; FS="\n"}
    NR==2 {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
            if($i !~ /^$/) {
                split($i,tmp,"#")
                i=i+1
                split($i,tmp2," ")
                printf "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", tmp[1],tmp[2],tmp2[2]
            }
        }
    }'
```

But I have another file type i.e.I'll be executing this command to 1000s of files in for loop but as of I have consolidated and only for below type it's not working as expected.

```
] cat testing.txt
ODSSLT_P09 COR-ODS-SMT9-B01 - 12/29/2015 -
SCHEDULE ODSSLT_P09#COR-ODS-SMT9-B01 TIMEZONE UTC
ON RUNCYCLE RULE1 "FREQ=DAILY;"
AT 0505
PRIORITY 11
:
ODSSLT_P09#CORODSSMT9001-01
UNTIL 2355 TIMEZONE Asia/Shanghai
EVERY 0100
ODSSLT_P09#CORODSSMT9001-02
AT 2355
EVERY 0100
ODSSLT_P09#CORODSSMT9001-03
ODSSLT_P09#CORODSSMT9001-04
UNTIL 2355 TIMEZONE Asia/Shanghai
EVERY 0100

EOF
```

Expected output for this file:

```
"ODSSLT_P09","CORODSSMT9001-01",""
"ODSSLT_P09","CORODSSMT9001-02","2355"
"ODSSLT_P09","CORODSSMT9001-03",""
"ODSSLT_P09","CORODSSMT9001-04",""
```

Actual output from the code is

```
| grep -v -i -w -E 
"CONFIRMED|DEADLINE|DAY|DAYS|EVERY|NEEDS|OPENS|PRIORITY|PROMPT|UNTIL|AWSBIA291I|END|FOLLOWS" |
awk 'BEGIN { RS=":"; FS="\n"}
NR==2 {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
  if($i !~ /^$/) {
    split($i,tmp,"#")
    i=i+1
    split($i,tmp2," ")
    printf "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", tmp[1],tmp[2],tmp2[2]
}}}'
```

output just gives:

```
"ODSSLT_P09","CORODSSMT9001-01",""
"AT 2355","",""
"ODSSLT_P09","CORODSSMT9001-04",""
```

Comment: `ksh` is great, but  you should be able to do all of this in one (maybe two) awk programs. Why complicate it? Or if you really want to use `ksh`, AND you can rely that your data after `:` will be in two-line pairs, you can insert another step after your first `awk` that "folds" each 2 lines onto one line, then you can just use `awk '{print $1, $3}' | awk -F# '{print $0}' | awk 'printf(...)` (using of course, a more rigourous `printf("\"%s\"....)` function to get your CSV data in order. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I have used this below

Comment: It would help if you would highlight the patterns that are relevant for the desited output.  I now guess that column 3 of that output should match the value after the string "UNTIL" if that would be present?  Don't leave us guessing, but explain what you need exactly.

A bit of explanation of the domain would help - are these flight or freight schedules?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be a small awk program doing everything (`awk` will loop through the input, so write something without a `while`).
Since you have tagged with ksh and not bash or linux, I do not trust your version of awk.
First try joining the lines and split again except for the AT. I hope no lines will have the string `EOL`, so I will join with an EOL marker.

```
   sed 's/$/EOL/' myfile.txt |
   tr -d "\n" |
   sed -e 's/EOLAT/ AT/g' -e 's/EOL/\n/g'
```

Perhaps your `sed` version will not understand the `\n`, in that case replace it with a real newline.
I know what I want to do with the `sed` output, so I will filter before sed and change the `sed` commands.

```
foundcolon="0";
grep -E "^:$|XSAP|AT" myfile.txt |
   sed 's/$/EOL/' |
   tr -d "\n" |
   sed -e 's/EOLAT//g' -e 's/EOL/\n/g' -e 's/#/ /g' |
   while read -r xsap corr numm rest_of_line; do
      if [ "${foundcolon}" = "0"  ]; then
         if [ "${xsap}" = ":" ]; then
            foundcolon="1"
         fi
         continue
      fi
      printf '"%s","%s","%s"\n' "${xsap}" "${corr}" "${numm}";
   done
```

Using another sed option, `sed -e '/address1/,/address2/ d'` will make it even more simple:

```
grep -E "^:$|XSAP|AT" myfile.txt |
   sed 's/$/EOL/' |
   tr -d "\n" |
   sed -e 's/EOLAT//g' -e 's/EOL/\n/g' -e '1,/^:$/ d' -e 's/#/ /g' |
   while read -r xsap corr numm rest_of_line; do
      printf '"%s","%s","%s"\n' "${xsap}" "${corr}" "${numm}";
   done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more or less pure `awk` solution, which produces literally the
requested output for the given input file.  It suffers from having no
knowledge of the problem domain.

```
awk '
/^:/ { start=1; next }
! start {next}
$1 == "AT" {
  split(last,a,/#/)
  printf "\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", a[1], a[2], $2
  last=""
  next
}
{
  last=$0
}' data
```

Comment: Thanks Henk, it worked, but it gives only the values of AT, but I would require the null values as well for the fields seperated by #. Please let me know if you could find a way on this. Thanking in anticipation!